# Cakephp Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: cakephp

I get the following errors: 
Notice (8): Undefined property: ProductsController::$Category
**

### Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

**  
in \shop\app\controllers\products_controller.php on line 7  
**Model:**

```
class Category extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Category';
var $hasMany = array('Product');
}
```

**Controller:**

```
class CategoriesController extends AppController{
var $name = 'Categories';}
class ProductsController extends AppController{
var $name ='Products';

function lists(){
$categories = $this->Category->find( 'all',array('order'=>'Category.id ASC'));
}
```

> i have two controller class 1. CategoriesController 2.
>   ProductsController. when i used lists method in categories controller,
>   it's work, but in products controller it give error?

Comment: Does your `Product` model actually have a `Category` attribute?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to call methods from Category (or other associated) model you have to do it through the 'parent' (in this case Prodcut) model:

`$categories = $this->Product->Category->find('all', array('order' => 'Category.id ASC'));`

should work.

see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#relationship-types